# How to remove Frame in RegionPlot while retaining the FrameLabel?

Tags: plotting

[image]

How can the `Frame` be removed in a `RegionPlot` while retaining the `FrameLabel`?

```
RegionPlot[{-1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis"}, FrameTicks -> {None, None},
  PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

#### 1.

Use `FrameStyle -> LineOpacity -> 0` (alternatively, `FrameStyle -> LineColor -> White`):

```
RegionPlot[{-1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1}, 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis"}, 
 FrameTicks -> None, 
 FrameStyle -> LineOpacity -> 0, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image]

#### 2.

Wrap `RegionPlot[...]` without frame with [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html):

```
Labeled[
  RegionPlot[{-1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1}, 
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Frame -> False, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True], 
  {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis"}, 
  {Bottom, Left},
  RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

#### 3.

Wrap `RegionPlot[...]` without frame with [`Panel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Panel.html) with the option `Background -> White`:

```
Panel[
  RegionPlot[{-1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   Frame -> False, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True],
 {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis"}, 
 {Bottom, Left}, 
 RotateLabel -> True, 
 Background -> White]
```

[image]